# scoped_by greater than or less than in ActiveRecord (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to use a dynamic scope in Rails where I filter by date. I want to do something like this:

```
Foo.scoped_by_created_on(>the_future).scoped_by_created_on(<the_past).find(:all)
```

Is this possible or am I stuck writing a :`conditions` hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `scoped_by` however you can make your own scopes for this.

```
named_scope :created_on_before, lambda { |time| { :conditions => ["created_on < ?", time] } }
named_scope :created_on_after, lambda { |time| { :conditions => ["created_on > ?", time] } }
```

Alternatively check out [Searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/tree/master) which offers named scopes for this.

```
Foo.created_on_greater_than(the_future).created_on_less_than(the_past)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a plugin called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) that offers you both a past and future method (amongst others) so you can do:

```
@foos = Foo.past(some_time) do
  Foo.future(some_other_time)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that as of Rails 3, a more concise approach is possible:

```
named_scope :created_between, -> (past,future) { where(created_on: past..future) }
```

Usage:

```
Foo.created_between(the_past,the_future)
```